# cakephp sql logs not showing

Tags: cakephp

Using `echo $this->element('sql_dmp');` is displaying  no queries made, but i'm getting data to use in my view. If i go into the `sql_dump.ctp` element and `print_r()` the `$logs` variable, i get this:

```
(
    [default] => Array
        (
            [log] => Array
                (
                )

            [count] => 0
            [time] => 
        )

)
```

What's going on? How do I proceed from here to find the problem? I'm using CakePHP 1.3 for reference.

Comment: 3 to be exact. I'm getting the table for the sql_dump, just not any data.

Comment: Are you doing any find queries on the page? If not there won't be any data.

Comment: yes, i am. 2 to be exact. one find->('all') and one find->('count')

Answer (score 0):

Bit late to the party, but maybe it is because you set your debug level to 3?
As far as I can see (haven't used Cake in quite some time), there is no debug level 3.

There is only

0: No error messages, warnings or errors shown

1: Errors and warnings shown, model caches refreshed, flash messages halted.

2: As in 1, but also with full debug messages and SQL output.

Those are not binary flags!

Maybe that's the reason?

Comment: That doesn't matter. Cake just checks if the debug is greater than, not equal to

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you made a typo in your question, but it should be `echo $this->element('sql_dump');`, not `echo $this->element('sql_dmp');`.

Answer (score 0):

The [CakePHP debug kit](https://github.com/cakephp/debug_kit) can help you. After you install it, you will notice a small (pie-chart) icon on the top right of your CakePHP pages. Clicking on that will allow you to see various useful information, and most importantly for this issue, all the SQL queries that occurred in the back-end upon the page loading.